# OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] Microsoft SQL: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql

My colleague who has left had mad a SQL query which don't want to run now because it keep saying that it returned more then 1 value.

The error is: OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] Microsoft SQL: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression..

Can you guys help me out here what I need to adjust in the query to make it run?

```
WITH emp_orgs AS
(SELECT e.TT_EMP_ID,
      soi.TT_ITEM AS Hoofdorganisatie

FROM tt_emp e
LEFT JOIN TT_VW_LABEL_EMP vle ON (e.TT_EMP_ID = vle.TT_DIM_ID)
LEFT JOIN TT_SYS_OPT_ITM soi ON (soi.TT_ITEM_ID = vle.TT_ITEM_ID)
AND soi.TT_OPT_ID = 5
AND soi.TT_CODE = 'TECH'),
  raster_hours_next_6_months AS
(SELECT e.TT_EMP_ID,

(SELECT sum(si.TT_HOURS)
  FROM TT_SYS_DAYS sd
  LEFT JOIN TT_EMP_SCHED es ON (es.TT_EMP_ID = e.TT_EMP_ID --outer table

                                AND es.TT_FROMDATE <= sd.TT_DATE
                                AND es.TT_TODATE >= sd.TT_DATE)
  LEFT JOIN TT_SCHEDDAY_ITM si ON (sd.TT_DATE = si.TT_DATE)
  WHERE sd.TT_DATE >= getdate()
    AND sd.TT_DATE <= DATEADD(MONTH, 6, getdate())
    AND si.TT_SCHED_ID = es.TT_SCHED_ID ) AS raster_hours_next_6_months,
(SELECT 1 - isnull(ec.TT_PERCNOTPLAN, 0)/100 --percentage dat kan worden gepland

  FROM TT_EMP_CONTRACT ec
  WHERE ec.TT_EMP_ID = e.TT_EMP_ID
    AND ec.TT_TODATE >= GETDATE() ) AS plannable_factor,
      eo.Hoofdorganisatie
  FROM TT_EMP e
  LEFT JOIN emp_orgs eo ON eo.TT_EMP_ID = e.TT_EMP_ID
  WHERE eo.Hoofdorganisatie IS NOT NULL )
  SELECT soi.TT_ITEM_ID as CategoryKey,

  (SELECT sum(r.raster_hours_next_6_months) / 6
   FROM raster_hours_next_6_months r
   WHERE r.Hoofdorganisatie = soi.TT_ITEM ) as ScheduledHours,

  (SELECT sum(r.raster_hours_next_6_months * r.plannable_factor) / 6
   FROM raster_hours_next_6_months r
   WHERE r.Hoofdorganisatie = soi.TT_ITEM ) as ScheduledHoursPlannable
   FROM TT_SYS_OPT_ITM soi
   WHERE soi.TT_OPT_ID = 5
   AND soi.TT_CODE = 'TECH'
```

Comment: _to make it run_, or to return a result that makes sense?

Comment: Return a result that makes sense.

Comment: A correlated subquery in the SELECT clause can instead be moved to the FROM clause, do a LEFT JOIN.